# How to add padding to detected OCR bounding boxes?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I am following: A tensorflow implementation of EAST text detector (https://github.com/argman/EAST#installation) tutorial.

When I execute the GitHub code linked above, on a image I get the following output:

[image]

The detection code is [eval.py](https://github.com/argman/EAST/blob/master/eval.py)

In the output I want to add padding to the generated bounding box so that I can capture first "K" and last "0" properly.

I changed box threshold on line 69 of the code. I tried different values ranging from 0.1, 0.05 etc, but the size of box does not change.

```
def detect(score_map, geo_map, timer, score_map_thresh=0.8, box_thresh=0.1, nms_thres=0.2):
```

How do I add padding to the bounding box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get into the function, find the line where the boxes are extracted. Each box will be represented either with 2 coordinates (top left and bottom right) or with one coordinate and the offset (top left point and height and width of the box). In both cases you have to subtract some amount of pixels from the top left corner of the bounding box and add some amount of pixels on the bottom right coordinate/height and width.
For example, let's say that the format is 2 coordinates and you get `((456, 234), (789, 453))`. Then when you do the math (subtract from top left and add to bottom right), you'll get something like `((470, 250), (800, 470))` I hope that's clear enough.

Comment: This technique works if I have to export the coordinated to a text file. However, the size of box that is the displayed square GUI is not increased. I am adding pixels to each coordinates while exporting it to text file, more precisely I am adding pixels to line 186 of https://github.com/argman/EAST/blob/master/eval.py.

Comment: You should do it in the part of the code starting with line `164`. Then you'll not have to do it anywhere else. It will be updated for saving and reading and drawing on the image (GUI, as you refer to it).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a long time ago. Simply add a margin to the bbox and then verify that it did not leave the image.
If you have bounding boxes:

```py
def expand(bbox, margin=5):
    # supose bbox is x1, y1, x2, y2
    return [
        bbox[0, 0] - margin,
        bbox[1] - margin,
        bbox[2] + margin,
        bbox[2] + margin]

bbox_expanded = expand(bbox)
img_crop = img[max(0, bbox[1]):min(img.shape[0], bbox[3]), max(bbox[0], 0):min(img.shape[1], bbox[2]), :]
```

If you have 4 points:

```
def expand(points, margin):
    # supose points is 1, p2, p3, p4
    return [
        [points[0, 0] - margin, points[0, 1] - margin],
        [points[1, 0] + margin, points[1, 1] - margin],
        [points[2, 0] + margin, points[2, 1] + margin],
        [points[3, 0] - margin, points[3, 1] + margin]]

points_expanded = expand(points)
```